# How to send commands to msys.bat through msbuild

Tags: msbuild, msys

Is it possible to use an MSBuild target to create a new msys.bat instance and run commands?

Comment: What is msys.bat and why do you need it?

Comment: msys.bat is a batch file that launches MinGW, a minimalist development environment for native Microsoft Windows applications, that is used for deployment.  I want to send commands to this through msbuild

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild has an [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) you can use to call a batch file or any executable:

```
<Exec Command="msys.bat param1 param2 param3" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass commands for that file to run as parameters or in some other way?

Comment: @Marissa Yes. Just include them in the Command attribute.  I've updated my answer.